# python syntax if in list function

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, if-statement

I am trying to find the proper python syntax to create a flag with a value of `yes` if `columnx` contains any of the following numbers: **`1, 2, 3, 4, 5`**.

```
def create_flag(df):
    if df['columnx'] in (1,2,3,4,5):
        return df['flag']=='yes'
```

I get the following error.

> TypeError: invalid type comparison

Is there an obvious mistake in my syntax?

Comment: Python is both case and space sensitive. The code you posted will raise a syntax error before it gets to type error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.where` with pandas `isin` as:

```
df['flag'] = np.where(df['columnx'].isin([1,2,3,4,5]),'yes','no')
```

Comment: TypeError: isin() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given  is the error i get

Comment: @pynewbee can you please check the syntax inside `isin` whether you have given list as `[1,2,3,4,5]` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You have lot of problems in your code! i assume you want to try something like this

```
def create_flag(df):
    if df['columnx'] in [1,2,3,4,5]:
        df['flag']='yes'

x = {"columnx":2,'flag':None}

create_flag(x)
print(x["flag"])
```